# Problem with my probability calculator in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, probability

Essentially I am making a probability calculator using Python.  It is meant to find the probability to finding a set number of balls after performing a set number of experiments **(could be a large number)**, where in each experiment, you draw a certain number of balls randomly from a hat.  I used object oriented programming to do this under the class Hat.
A hat object can be created this way:

```
hat = Hat(blue=3,red=2,green=6)
```

The class should take a variable number of arguments that specify the number of balls of each color that are in the hat. Here the hat contains `3 blue balls, 2 red balls and 6 green balls.`

Outside the class, there is a function called experiment that works out the probability of drawing certain type of balls **(expected_balls)** from a argument called `'hat'` when you decide to draw a set number of balls **(num_balls_drawn)** after performing a certain number of experiments **(num_experiments)**.  The certain balls can be balls of different colors or styles.  So a typical way/example of calling the experiment function is:

```
probability = experiment(hat=hat, expected_balls={"blue":2,"green":1}, num_balls_drawn=4, num_experiments=1000)
```

The probabilities produced each time the code is run should vary slightly.  I was testing my code with this object and specific function call:

```
hat = Hat(blue=3,red=2,green=6)
probability = experiment(hat=hat, expected_balls={"blue":2,"green":1}, num_balls_drawn=4, num_experiments=1000)
```

While my probabilities varied slightly and produce probabilities between `0.31` and `0.39`, the expected probability is actually `0.272` or values close to that probability **(with a difference of 0.01)**.  So it appears that I am far off.  However, I can't quite work out what the problem is and how to fix it.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

THE CODE

```
import copy
import random

class Hat:
    
    def __init__(self,**ball):
        self.contents = list() #holds the balls
        ball_and_count = list() #list for colour of ball and its count 
        for key, value in ball.items():
            ball_and_count.append(f"{key}= {value}")
        #print(ball_and_count)
        for i in ball_and_count:
            equal_pos = i.find("=")
            ball_type = i[:equal_pos] #using string splicing to find ball type
            count = int(i[equal_pos+1:])#using string splicing to find the number of balls of that type
            c = 0
            while c < count:
                self.contents.append(ball_type)
                c = c + 1
    def draw(self,num)
        self.num = num
        c = 0 #used in a while loop
        drawed_ball = list() #this is where all the balls that were drawed out from contents will stay
        try:
            while c < self.num:
                drawed_ball.append(self.contents.pop(random.randint(0,len(self.contents)-1)))
                c = c + 1
            return drawed_ball
        except:
            return drawed_ball

     
def experiment(hat, expected_balls,num_balls_drawn, num_experiments):
    M = 0
    exp_done = 0
    while exp_done < num_experiments:
        drawn = 0
        drawn_balls = list()
        while drawn < num_balls_drawn:
            dc_contents = copy.deepcopy(hat.contents) # we are creating a deep copy of hat contents so that hat.contents stays the same
            drawn_balls.append(dc_contents.pop(random.randint(0,len(dc_contents)-1))) #append to the drawn_balls list
            v = 0
            for key, val in expected_balls.items():
                if key in drawn_balls:
                    k = drawn_balls.count(key) 
                    if k >= val:#here we are checking if for one ball type, we are drew the expected number of balls, then we increment the variable v
                        v = v + 1
        
            if v == len(expected_balls):#we check if we have drawn the expected no. balls for all the balls and types, either we did or we did not, no in between, then we increment the variable M
                M = M + 1            
            
            #incrementing the number of balls drawn  
            drawn = drawn + 1
        exp_done = exp_done + 1 #incrementing the number of experiments drawn
        
    N = num_experiments
    prob = M / N
    return prob
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This is not a code-writing or tutoring service.  While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're copying a fresh hat after every draw. By doing so, you compute the odds of drawing those balls while replacing them after every draft, while it appears you want to compute the odds of drawing specific balls from a series of drafts without replacing them. You're also not initialising `M`, so your code won't run as presented.

Comment: Also, you're checking for the condition after every draw, and counting the results in a very odd way, which seems to make fairly little sense - perhaps you were aiming to stop drawing as soon as the goal was reached? That logic is currently flawed.

Comment: Hi there, for the M = 0 part. i must have accidentally deleted it when I was copying the code here, though it was originally there in my code. thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Also, I am trying to check if for every draw, like for the specific function call, I am getting at least 2 blue balls and 1 green ball. So I am including the scenarios when I am getting 2 blue and 1 green or more than that.

Answer (score 0):

There's more efficient ways to approach the problem, but following your original structure:

```
def experiment(hat, expected_balls, num_balls_drawn, num_experiments):
    exp_done = 0
    M = 0
    while exp_done < num_experiments:
        drawn = 0
        drawn_balls = list()
        dc_contents = copy.deepcopy(
            hat.contents)  # we are creating a deep copy of hat contents so that hat.contents stays the same
        while drawn < num_balls_drawn:
            drawn_balls.append(
                dc_contents.pop(random.randint(0, len(dc_contents) - 1)))  # append to the drawn_balls list
            for key, val in expected_balls.items():
                if drawn_balls.count(key) < val:
                    break
            else:
                M += 1
                break

            drawn += 1
        exp_done += 1  # incrementing the number of experiments drawn

    N = num_experiments
    prob = M / N
    return prob
```

Problems that had to be fixed:

- you were resetting the hat after every ball drawn, the `deepcopy` needs to be outside the loop
- your check routine counted a success as soon as each required type was drawn

Runnable:

```
import copy
import random

class Hat:
    def __init__(self,**ball):
        self.contents = list() #holds the balls
        ball_and_count = list() #list for colour of ball and its count
        for key, value in ball.items():
            ball_and_count.append(f"{key}= {value}")
        #print(ball_and_count)
        for i in ball_and_count:
            equal_pos = i.find("=")
            ball_type = i[:equal_pos] #using string splicing to find ball type
            count = int(i[equal_pos+1:])#using string splicing to find the number of balls of that type
            c = 0
            while c < count:
                self.contents.append(ball_type)
                c = c + 1

    def draw(self,num):
        self.num = num
        c = 0 #used in a while loop
        drawed_ball = list() #this is where all the balls that were drawed out from contents will stay
        try:
            while c < self.num:
                drawed_ball.append(self.contents.pop(random.randint(0,len(self.contents)-1)))
                c = c + 1
            return drawed_ball
        except:
            return drawed_ball


def experiment(hat, expected_balls, num_balls_drawn, num_experiments):
    exp_done = 0
    M = 0
    while exp_done < num_experiments:
        drawn = 0
        drawn_balls = list()
        dc_contents = copy.deepcopy(
            hat.contents)  # we are creating a deep copy of hat contents so that hat.contents stays the same
        while drawn < num_balls_drawn:
            drawn_balls.append(
                dc_contents.pop(random.randint(0, len(dc_contents) - 1)))  # append to the drawn_balls list
            for key, val in expected_balls.items():
                if drawn_balls.count(key) < val:
                    break
            else:
                M += 1
                break

            drawn += 1
        exp_done += 1  # incrementing the number of experiments drawn

    N = num_experiments
    prob = M / N
    return prob


hat = Hat(blue=3,red=2,green=6)
probability = experiment(hat=hat, expected_balls={"blue":2,"green":1}, num_balls_drawn=4, num_experiments=1000)
print(probability)
```

This prints values like `0.288` - how you'd be getting values like `8.0` is a mystery to me, but I'm fairly certain this isn't actually the code you're running. (and thus you weren't running the solution given with your code - that still has a typo and won't run on `def draw(self,num)` anyway)

Comment: Hey I tried it with the changes you made.  However, I am getting probabilities much greater that are over 0.8.  So I am not sure what to do after this...

Comment: Hi there, I ran it again and I managed to get values around 0.28. Thank you for this! I think when I first ran it, I got confused by the if and else statement (after the< for key,val in expected_balls> line) in the experiment function as they were not indented the same way (assumed that was a typo). So I indented it thinking that is how the code was supposed to be.  Therefore, I got 0.8.  When I copied the code as it is, I got 0.28.  However, I have not passed the test because the test_module gives an error essentially saying that 0.291 (generated probability)  != 0.272 (expected probability).

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it! I'm relieved. I just simply made some adjustments on my draw method in the Hat class.  Then I used the draw method in the experiment function, as well as the changes that  you (Grismar) mentioned.  Thank you so so much!

```
import copy
import random

class Hat:
    
    def __init__(self,**ball):
        self.contents = list() #holds the balls
        ball_and_count = list() #list for colour of ball and its count 
        for key, value in ball.items():
            ball_and_count.append(f"{key}= {value}")
        #print(ball_and_count)
        for i in ball_and_count:
            equal_pos = i.find("=")
            ball_type = i[:equal_pos] #using string splicing to find ball type
            count = int(i[equal_pos+1:])#using string splicing to find the number of balls of that type
            c = 0
            while c < count:
                self.contents.append(ball_type)
                c = c + 1
     
    def draw(self,num):
        self.num = num
        c = 0 #used in a while loop
        drawed_ball = list() #this is where all the balls that were drawed out from contents will stay
        if self.num <= len(self.contents):
            while c < self.num:
                drawed_ball.append(self.contents.pop(random.randint(0,len(self.contents)-1)))
                c = c + 1
            return drawed_ball
        else:
            drawed_ball = self.contents
            return drawed_ball
        
def experiment(hat, expected_balls, num_balls_drawn, num_experiments):
    exp_done = 0
    M = 0
    while exp_done < num_experiments:
        dc_contents = copy.deepcopy(hat)  # we are creating a deep copy of hat contents so that hat.contents stays the same
        drawn_balls = dc_contents.draw(num_balls_drawn)
        
        for key,val in expected_balls.items():
            if drawn_balls.count(key) < val:
                break
        
        else:
            M += 1
        
        exp_done += 1  # incrementing the number of experiments drawn

    N = num_experiments
    prob = M / N
    return prob
```